# How to access vectors inside local in drRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I do not know if this is the right question for my problem, I am a beginner and english is not my native language (obviously), Sorry for any mistakes.

I have this code, it is about presidential elections, a person has to type name, gender and id number, but it can only vote once, so the same id number cannot be used again. I do not know how to do that.

I have tried accessing the vector containing the information about the last person who voted and comparing it with the information about the person that is voting right now. But I dont know how or where to use this function.

```
  (define (access_vec numId)
        (cond
             [(equal? (vector-ref vote 2) numId) "Type different Id"]
             [else (set! vote (vector name gender idNum))]))
```

```
(define (elections)
  (local
    (
     (define-struct voter (name gender idNum))
     (define vote empty)
     (define data 0)
     (define data2 0)
     (define data3 0)
     (define option 0)
     (define name 0)
     (define gender 0)
     (define idNum 0)


     (define (candidate1)
       (begin
         (printf "type name: ")
         (set! name (read))
         (printf "type gender: ")
         (set! gender (read))
         (printf "type id: ")
         (set! idNum (read))
         (set! vote (vector name gender idNum) )
         (displayln "\n______________\n")
         (displayln "\nVoter Certificate\n")
         (display "Name: ")
         (set! data (displayln name))
          (display "Gender: ")
         (set! data2 (displayln gender))
          (display "Id: ")
         (set! data3 (displayln idNum))
         (displayln "\n______________\n")

        )
      )



  (define (candidate2)
       (begin
         (printf "type name: ")
         (set! name (read))
         (printf "type gender: ")
         (set! gender (read))
         (printf "type id: ")
         (set! idNum (read))
         (set! vote (vector name gender idNum) )
         (displayln "\n______________\n")
         (displayln "\nVoter Certificate\n")
         (display "Name: ")
         (set! datos (displayln name))
          (display "Gender: ")
         (set! datos2 (displayln gender))
          (display "Id: ")
         (set! datos3 (displayln idNum))
         (displayln "\n______________\n")

        )
      )

     (define (show)
       (write vote)
      )
     (define (menu)
       (begin
         (printf "~n***ELECTIONS***~n1. candidate1 ~n")
         (printf "2. candidate2 ~n")      
         (printf "3. show ~n")

         (printf "4. Exit ~n")
         (set! option (read))
         (cond 
           [(= option 1) (begin
                           (candidate1)
                           (menu))]

            [(= option 2) (begin
                           (candidate2)
                           (menu))]

           [(= option 3) (begin
                           (show)
                           (menu))]
           [(= option 4) (printf "GoodBye")]
          )
        )
      )
     )
    (menu)))

(elections)
```

I want to know how do I make this work: a person can vote only once. or any tips regarding anything that would make this code better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner and english is not my native language too.
There lots way to solve this.
You can read racket doc to understand all syntax sugar in here. And one day you can write all syntax suagr by yourself.

In here I don't write clear code because the logic is simple.
If you use this code than when candidates electorate change you don't need to change any code.

```
#lang racket
(define-struct person (name gender idNum voted-to) #:transparent #:mutable)

;;; data
(define candidate-list
  '(cand1 cand2 cand3))

(define person-list
  (list
   (person 'Mike 'man 0 #f)
   (person 'Mike1 'woman 1 #f)
   (person 'Mike2 'man 2 #f)
   (person 'Mike3 'woman 3 #f)
   (person 'Mike4 'man 4 #f)
   (person 'Bad1 'woman 5 #f)
   (person 'Bad2 'woman 6 #f)
   (person 'Bad3 'man 7 #f)
   (person 'Bad4 'orther 8 #f)
   (person 'Bad5 'orther 9 #f)))

;;; can-vote? : person -> boolean
(define (can-vote? a-person)
  (local ((define p-on-list
            (filter (lambda (p) (and (symbol=? (person-name p) (person-name a-person))
                                     (= (person-idNum p) (person-idNum a-person))
                                     (symbol=? (person-gender p) (person-gender a-person))))
                    person-list)))
    (cond
      ; in list?
      [(empty? p-on-list)
       #f]
      ; not vote yet?
      [(false? (person-voted-to (first p-on-list)))   
       #t]
      [else #f])))


;;; we don't check want-vote-cand legal or not
;;; because in real world also allow rejected ballot
;;; vote-machine : person symbol -> string
(define (vote-machine p want-vote-cand)
  (if (can-vote? p)
      (begin
        (map (lambda (p1) (if (= (person-idNum p) (person-idNum p1))
                              (set-person-voted-to! p1 want-vote-cand)
                              p1))
             person-list)
        "vote ok")
      "can't vote"))

;;; TEST
(vote-machine (person 'Mike 'man 0 #f) 'cand1)
(vote-machine (person 'Mike 'man 0 #f) 'cand2) ; vote twice
(vote-machine (person 'Mike1 'woman 1 #f) 'cand4) ; wrong vote
(vote-machine (person 'Mike2 'man 2 #f) 'bad-ticket) ; wrong vote
(vote-machine (person 'Mike3 'woman 3 #f) 'bad-ticket) ; wrong vote
(vote-machine (person 'Mike4 'man 4 #f) 'cand2) 
(vote-machine (person 'Bad1 'woman 5 #f) 'cand2) 
(vote-machine (person 'Bad2 'woman 6 #f) 'cand2)
(vote-machine (person 'Bad3 'woman 6 #f) 'cand2) ; wrong id
(vote-machine (person 'Bad3 'man 7 #f) 'cand3)
(vote-machine (person 'Bad3 'man 7 #f) 'cand1) ; vote twice
(vote-machine (person 'Bad3 'man 7 #f) 'cand2) ; vote twice

;;; TEST
; after voting person-list
person-list

;;; classification : listof-symbol listof-person -> listof-listof-person
(define (classification cand-list p-list result)
  (cond
    [(empty? cand-list)
     result]
    [else
     (classification
      (rest cand-list)
      p-list
      (cons (filter (λ (p) (equal? (first cand-list)
                                   (person-voted-to p)))
                    p-list) result))]))

(define (show-outcome candidate-list people-ls)
  (map (lambda (l1 l2)
         (list l2 "get" l1 "ticket"))
       (map length (classification candidate-list people-ls empty))
       candidate-list))

;;; TEST
(classification candidate-list person-list empty)
(show-outcome candidate-list person-list)
```

all output should be

```
"vote ok"
"can't vote"
"vote ok"
"vote ok"
"vote ok"
"vote ok"
"vote ok"
"vote ok"
"can't vote"
"vote ok"
"can't vote"
"can't vote"

; after voting person-list
(list
 (person 'Mike 'man 0 'cand1)
 (person 'Mike1 'woman 1 'cand4)
 (person 'Mike2 'man 2 'bad-ticket)
 (person 'Mike3 'woman 3 'bad-ticket)
 (person 'Mike4 'man 4 'cand2)
 (person 'Bad1 'woman 5 'cand2)
 (person 'Bad2 'woman 6 'cand2)
 (person 'Bad3 'man 7 'cand3)
 (person 'Bad4 'orther 8 #f)
 (person 'Bad5 'orther 9 #f))

; classification 
(list
 (list (person 'Bad3 'man 7 'cand3))
 (list
  (person 'Mike4 'man 4 'cand2)
  (person 'Bad1 'woman 5 'cand2)
  (person 'Bad2 'woman 6 'cand2))
 (list (person 'Mike 'man 0 'cand1)))

; show-outcome
'((cand1 "get" 1 "ticket")
  (cand2 "get" 3 "ticket")
  (cand3 "get" 1 "ticket"))
```

Upgrade a simple version

```
;;; data
(define person-name-ls
  (list 'Mike 'Mike1 'Mike2 'Mike3 'Mike4 'Mike5 'Mike6 'Mike7 'Mike8 'Mike9))

(define person-gender-ls
  (list 'man 'woman 'man 'woman 'man 'woman 'man 'woman 'man 'woman 'man))

(define person-id-ls
  '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(define vote-result empty)

(define (person-check-ok? name gender id)
  (local ((define ref-posn (indexes-where person-id-ls (lambda (n) (equal? id n)))))
    (cond
      [(empty? ref-posn)
       #f]
      [else
       (and (symbol=? (list-ref person-name-ls (first ref-posn)) name)
            (symbol=? (list-ref person-gender-ls (first ref-posn)) gender))])))

(define (alread-vote id)
  (set! person-id-ls
        (map (λ (x) (if (equal? x id) #f x))
             person-id-ls)))

(define (vote-machine name gender id want-vote)
  (cond
    [(person-check-ok? name gender id)
     (begin
       (alread-vote id)
       (set! vote-result (cons want-vote vote-result))
       "vote finish")]
    [else "can't vote"]))

;;; TEST

(vote-machine 'Mike 'man 0 'cand1)
(vote-machine 'Mike1 'woman 1 'cand3)
(vote-machine 'Mike2 'man 2 'bad-ticket)
(vote-machine 'Mike3 'woman 3 'bad-ticket) 
(vote-machine 'Mike4 'man 4 'bad-ticket)
(vote-machine 'Mike5 'woman 5 'cand2) 
(vote-machine 'Mike6 'man 6 'cand2) 
(vote-machine 'Mike7 'woman 7 'cand3)
(vote-machine 'Mike8 'man 8 'cand3)
(vote-machine 'Mike1 'man 0 'cand2) ; vote twice
(vote-machine 'Mike3 'woman 3 'cand3) ; vote twice
(vote-machine 'Mike-x 'man 9 'cand2) ; wrong person data

(define (show-ticket-number candidate-name)
  (count (lambda (x) (symbol=? x candidate-name)) vote-result))

;;; TEST
(show-ticket-number 'cand1)
(show-ticket-number 'cand2)
(show-ticket-number 'cand3)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. There are many things I do not understand in what you wrote, like lambda for example. I am beginner beginner, I know about the racket doc but beacuse of the language there are many things I do not get. I will search the web for answers to see how can I work with what you wrote. Thanks again.

Comment: f(x):=x^2 <=> (lambda (x) (sqr x)) ;
f(2) <=> ((lambda (x) (sqr x)) 2) ;

g(x,y):=x^2-y <=> (lambda (x y) (- (sqr x) y)) ;
g(1,2) <=> ((lambda (x y) (- (sqr x) y)) 1 2)

Comment: I just write a simple version enjoy. @DavidHume